# Is $C(C(\mathbb R))$ notation for the set of continuous functions mapping $C(\mathbb R)$ to itself?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, notation

Given that in general functional analysis we have $C(\mathbb{R})$ being the set of all continuous functions, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. However, could I use $C(C(\mathbb{R}))$ notationally to be the the set of all continuous functions, $f: C(\mathbb{R})\to C(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $C(M)$ is usually understood as $C(M,\mathbb{R})$. So for your purpose a better notation should be $C(C(\mathbb{R}), C(\mathbb{R}))$.

Comment: To define a continuous function on a set, you need a notion of a topology or a metric on that set. There are multiple nice-looking metrics and topologies you could pick on $C(\Bbb R)$ some with different notions of continuity.

Comment: Whatever it turns out to be, just don't abbreviate it $C^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not standard and is not likely to be understood as intended.  As Sam points out in a comment,

> $C(M)$ is usually understood as $C(M,\mathbb R)$. So for your purpose a better notation should be $C(C(\mathbb R),C(\mathbb R))$.

Furthermore, echoing PVAL's comment, it is not obvious what topology you have in mind on $C(\mathbb R)$, and this needs to be specified in order to determine what is meant by "continuous" for functions to or from this space.

Comment: what topologies are there to choose from?

Comment: Google could help you more than I can.  If you have a more specific question, e.g. including context of what you want it for, you could post it as a new question.